# Pandas Dataframe - Adding Else?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, training-data, bayesian-networks

I want to generate Test Data for my Bayesian Network.
This is my current Code:

```
data = np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 6))
columns = ['p_1', 'p_2', 'OP1', 'OP2', 'OP3', 'OP4']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df.loc[(df['p_1'] == 1) & (df['p_2'] == 1), 'OP1'] = 1

df.loc[(df['p_1'] == 1) & (df['p_2'] == 0), 'OP2'] = 1

df.loc[(df['p_1'] == 0) & (df['p_2'] == 1), 'OP3'] = 1

df.loc[(df['p_1'] == 0) & (df['p_2'] == 0), 'OP4'] = 1


print(df)
```

So every time, for example, p_1 has a 1 and p_2 has a 1, the OP1 should be 1 as well, all the other values should output 0 in the column.
When p_1 is 1 and p_2 is 0, then OP2 should be 1 an d all others 0, and so on.

But my current Output is the following:

| p_1 | p_2 |  | OP1 | OP2 | OP3 | OP4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |  | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Is there any way to fix it? What did I do wrong?

I didn't really understand the solutions to other peoples questions, so I thought Id ask here.

I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you instantiate `df`, the "OP" columns already have some values:

```
data = np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 6)) 
columns = ['p_1', 'p_2', 'OP1', 'OP2', 'OP3', 'OP4'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns) 

df                                                                      

   p_1  p_2  OP1  OP2  OP3  OP4
0    1    1    0    1    0    0
1    0    0    1    1    0    1
2    0    1    1    1    0    0
3    1    1    1    1    0    1
4    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

One way of fixing it with your code is forcing all "OP" columns to 0 before:

```
df["OP1"] = df["OP2"] = df["OP3"] df["OP4"] = 0
```

But then you are generating too many random numbers. I'd do this instead:

```
data = np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 2)) 
columns = ['p_1', 'p_2'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns) 
df["OP1"] = ((df['p_1'] == 0) & (df['p_2'] == 1)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can defined tuples for test and create new columns by casting values of mask to inetegers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
vals = [(1,1),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)]
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(vals, 1):
    df[f'OP{i}'] = ((df['p_1'] == a) & (df['p_2'] == b)).astype(int)
print(df)
   p_1  p_2  OP1  OP2  OP3  OP4
0    0    0    0    0    0    1
1    0    1    0    0    1    0
2    0    1    0    0    1    0
3    0    1    0    0    1    0
4    1    0    0    1    0    0
```

In your solution set `0` first, because already are set `1` values in original `DataFrame`:

```
cols = ['OP1', 'OP2', 'OP3', 'OP4']
df[cols] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Problem solved! :)

Comment: @Larumee - You are welcome! so another answer working better?